# if true inside a formatted string

Tags: python, if-statement, nested

I have two names to display on a single print statement along with if they are selected for a group and want the output to read something like:
"account name: John (Unaffiliated)          account name: Russel (Premium)"
my names are under account.name and im using account.group for True or False statements, so im looking to see how to do the following.

```
account1 = accounts(self, name, group)
account2 = accounts(self, name, group)

account1.name = "John"
account2.name = "Russel"
account1.group = False
account2.group = True

print (f"account name: {str(account1.name)} if account1.group is True {str"(Premium)"} else {str"
(Unaffiliated)":10} f"account name: {str(account2.name)} if account2.group is True {str"(Premium)"} else
{str"(Unaffiliated)"}\n")
```

I'm not sure how to or if I can insert a if statement like this or what a more efficient way to get what im looking for but any advice is welcome.
On a side note there is a class created called accounts but I didn't think it was relevant to insert in my example

I get a syntax error by default, which doesn't surprise me.

Comment: Don't try and do everything inside an `f` string. You can, and *should* break this out using either variables to stage the value being substituted, or using the `%s` style placeholder where you can get more ambitious with your computations in an easier to read block of code that's just a normal argument to `format()`.

Comment: You can use python's ternary expressions. Something like: `f'{"(Premium)" if account1.group else "(Unaffiliated)"}'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syntax is incorrect as well -  I think this is what you're after.

```
account1_name = "John"
account2_name = "Russel"
account1_group = False
account2_group = True

print(f'account name: {account1_name} ({"Premium" if account1_group is True  else "Unaffiliated"})')

print(f'account name: {account2_name} ({"Premium" if account2_group is True  else "Unaffiliated"})')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [ternary operator](https://docs.python.org/3.10/reference/expressions.html?highlight=ternary#conditional-expressions) to achieve this.

`print(f'{"Premium" if account.name is True else "Unaffiliated"}')`

However, it should be noted that putting too much inside a f-string can negatively affect the readability of your code and it is suggested to use variables or the [.format() method](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_format.asp) for aspects like this.